# rewrite url using .htaccess and add back slash

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I am new in htaccess url rewrite. I have a dynamic cms website. I was rewrite this url  **http:// exampl.com/?ca=home&bb=tech** in to **http://exampl.com/home/tech/**.

The htaccess code is:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?ca=$1&bb=$2 [L]
```

When a user has forgotten to add the backslash into the url it will be redirected to the error page 
eg :

```
 http://exampl.com/home/tech - redirected in to error page
```

How to avoid and automaticaly add **backslash(/)**  on the url using  htaccess.

Comment: I don't understand, **slash** is **/**, while **backslash** is **\\** ... which are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly add a backslash you can put this rule above the one that you already have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise, you could make the trailing slash optional by adding a **?** to your existing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?ca=$1&bb=$2 [L]
```